# Remote server not found in XMPP

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, remote-server

i send Packet to client

```
      <iq id="kGufc-4" to="tp@localhsot" from="admin@localhost" type="get"><query xmlns='http://localhost/protocol/disco#info'/></iq>
```

And received

```
   <iq id="kGufc-4" to="admin@localhost/testchat" from="tp@localhsot" type="error"><error code="404" type="CANCEL"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

what is problem???

Comment: you are using "localhsot" instead of "localhost" somewhere in your code.

Comment: thanks..but after this correction  nothing response is returned

Comment: check your domain name at the server side also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems with that stanza.

1) You've typod 'localhsot' instead of 'localhost'.

2) You're putting a 'from' on the stanza. Assuming you're a client sending this, it is better to not use a 'from', and let the server stamp it itself, as if you get the 'from' wrong, the server will start rejecting stanzas. In your case it's wrong as you're using the bare JID of the client, not the full JID.

Try resolving those first, and then seeing what happens.

Comment: Also, the to address probably needs a resource, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.