# Remote server not found in asmack-xmpp chat

Tags: android, xmpp, http-status-code-404, chat, asmack

I added chat features in my app. Code work fine upto get `RosterList` from chat server. 
[image]

But get below error while sending chat message

```
D/SMACK: 11:30:02 AM SENT (600971785): <message id="c2b06df7-c232-41b0-a62b-cfbf060f716f" to="2@domainname.com" type="chat"><body>{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;text&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:&quot;hii&quot;,&quot;msgID&quot;:&quot;c2b06df7-c232-41b0-a62b-cfbf060f716f&quot;,&quot;thumb_url&quot;:&quot;&quot;}</body></message>

D/SMACK: 11:30:02 AM RCV  (600971785): <message id="c2b06df7-c232-41b0-a62b-cfbf060f716f" to="58@domainname.com" from="2@domainname.com" type="error"><error code="404" type="cancel"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></message>
```

I also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353667/remote-server-not-found-in-xmpp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838663/smack-on-android-getting-error-code-404-remote-server-not-found-while-sending) , but I can't get my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **don't put anything other than human-readable text in the `<body/>` of messages**. Follow [this advice](http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/index.php?title=XMPP_IM_Client_Design_Guidelines#When_making_a_custom_extension.2C_add_new_elements_to_.3Cmessage.3E.2C_.3Ciq.3E_or_.3Cpresence.3E_stanzas) to add custom data to XMPP messages.

The `remote-server-not-found` means that your XMPP server was unable to connect to the XMPP server for the domain you tried to send the message to. You have to make sure that `domainname.com` is the correct domain for the account `2`.

Comment: I just get/set `json` object in message and parse it in code.
and I check my `demainname`, which is fine.

Comment: You should check the server's logs, to see why it's trying and failing to connect to `domainname.com`.